# Broccoli error when trying to do ember tutorial

Tags: ember.js, broccolijs, ember-cli-mirage

I am at the last step of this part of the ember.js tutorial.
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/tutorial/installing-addons/

I receive this error when attempting to run the ember server after adding the `ember-cli-mirage` addon.

```
steven@steven-VirtualBox:~/em-test$ ember s
Could not start watchman
Visit https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
Livereload server on http://localhost:49153
'instrument' is imported from external module 'ember-data/-debug' but never used
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliMergeTrees: Addon#treeFor (ember-cli-mirage - addon)] failed with:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /home/steven/em-test/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/lib/strategies/persistent.js:35:23
    at tryCatch (/home/steven/em-test/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (/home/steven/em-test/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:13)
    at /home/steven/em-test/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:606:14
    at flush (/home/steven/em-test/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2415:5)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:436:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:365:13)
```

Any help parsing this stack? Not sure what any of this is doing at the moment, just trying to get through the tutorial.

Comment: What versions are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at your code it would be difficult to help you, but here's a clue:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
Check that you're not missing a closing tag or something simple.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I restarted the tutorial in a new directory and have gotten past that point. I did a diff on the directories and the only thing that has changed is the package-lock.json. I guess I had some old npm packages that broke it.

Comment: @StevenB - so this question is over?

Comment: Yes I suppose it is.